# Backing up from Dropbox (online) straight to external drive

Tags: hard-drive, mac, backup, external-hard-drive, dropbox

I have all my work saved on my Dropbox account, and generally only have around 20% of that stored locally at any one time.

I'd like to buy a large external drive and back everything up onto that for safe keeping, but I don't have enough room on my harddrive to download all my Dropbox and then copy it over onto the external drive.

Is the only solution to manually back things up one folder at a time?

Bear in mind this is on a Mac too (but thought this forum would be more suited)

Comment: [Why don't you just sychronize a location on the other drive?](https://help.dropbox.com/guide/individual/how-to-sync-files-folders#sync-across-devices).

Comment: @Ramhound do you mean I can sync to my external drive aswell as my computer? I can't find anything relating to that on the link you shared?

Comment: [The article was suppose to talk about selective folder selection.  My suggestion is to synchronize your full dropbox on the external drive instead of your internal drive.](https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/sync-uploads/selective-sync-overview)

Comment: @Ramhound Would that not make things really slow? Unless I were to copy any files over to my computer whenever I wanted to work on them, but that wouldnt be ideal either

Comment: You didn't specify the specifications of the external drive.  USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 and Thunderbolt 3 are nearly as fast as NVMe drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I back up online Dropbox content straight to a hard drive?

My personal experience indicates that you will probably need to script a solution yourself.

Dropbox has an API which allows direct access to files from the command line, but it can be less than ideal to work with. In short, with both suggestions offered below, I haven't found an easy way to tell Dropbox to download "everything", starting with the root folder and proceeding through sub-folders.

**dbxcli**

[dbxcli](https://github.com/dropbox/dbxcli) is the official command line client for Dropbox built with [Go](https://github.com/dropbox/dbxcli).

Stand-alone, compiled versions of `dbxcli` for several operating systems are available from their [official GitHub Releases](https://github.com/dropbox/dbxcli/releases) page. Note that there are Mac OSX installation instructions on the main page.

To download "everything", I found needed to wrap `dbxcli` in a script so I could parse its output (which presented its own challenges due to how `dbxcli` chooses to format that output). I was then able to collect all the relevant data regarding the contents of my Dropbox account and tell `dbxcli` to (repeatedly) download the proper files/folders. This could possibly be simpler if you already had a text list of files to download.

**dropbox (Python)**

[Python](https://www.python.org/) is a generally user-friendly, cross-platform scripting language with a lot of optional additions called "modules". One such module is [dropbox](https://pypi.org/project/dropbox/), the official Python Dropbox API module for Dropbox.

The downsides of the `dropbox` module ultimately boil down to more complexity. You will need to:

- Have a passing familiarity with Python (or be willing to learn).
- Handle logging in yourself.
- Catch any exceptions the API may throw at you (one common exception I encountered was a `StoneValidtor` exception, which I wasn't immediately clear in how to catch).
- Handle long file names/paths specially (assuming this is an issue for you).
- Handle names with Unicode characters in a special manner, depending on whether or not you are using Windows `cmd`.

On top of this, the Dropbox API documentation seem squarely aimed at developers. Lots of technical data to sort through and minimal (overall) usage examples.

Also, you will still need to recursively handle collecting Dropbox file folders/file names yourself and repeatedly download those files in an automated fashion.

---

*As a "best of both worlds" approach, `dropbox` could be used to recursively collect folder/file information, which could be then fed to `dbxcli`. This would likely cut out some more of the annoying issues with either solution alone.*